# Maven - Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Tags: java, maven

I know this question has been posted a lot, but I still can't resolve my problem.

So, I just downloaded a `bin` distribution from http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip

after extracting the zip file, I moved it to `/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9`

Here's how my terminal look like when I run the commands:

```
xxx@xxx-VirtualBox:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin$ ls
m2.conf  mvn  mvnDebug

xxx@xxx-VirtualBox:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin$ ./mvn
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

xxx@xxx-VirtualBox:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

xxx@xxx-VirtualBox:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin$ printenv JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Java is installed correctly, but I still can't run the `mvn` executable file

The result of `ls -lR /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9` is as follows:

```
xxx@xxx-VirtualBox:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin$ ls -lR /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/
/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 21 11:12 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 21 11:12 boot
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Dec  9  2015 conf -> /etc/maven
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 21 11:12 lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 21 11:12 man

/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:
total 12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Dec  9  2015 m2.conf -> /etc/maven/m2.conf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7383 Nov 19  2015 mvn
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1815 Nov 19  2015 mvnDebug

/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/boot:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Dec  9  2015 plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar -> ../../java/plexus-classworlds2.jar

/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/lib:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dec  9  2015 aopalliance.jar -> ../../java/aopalliance.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Dec  9  2015 cdi-api.jar -> ../../java/cdi-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dec  9  2015 commons-cli.jar -> ../../java/commons-cli.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Dec  9  2015 commons-io.jar -> ../../java/commons-io.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Dec  9  2015 commons-lang3.jar -> ../../java/commons-lang3.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Dec  9  2015 commons-lang.jar -> ../../java/commons-lang.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Dec  9  2015 eclipse-aether-api.jar -> ../../java/eclipse-aether-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Dec  9  2015 eclipse-aether-connector-basic.jar -> ../../java/eclipse-aether-connector-basic.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Dec  9  2015 eclipse-aether-impl.jar -> ../../java/eclipse-aether-impl.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Dec  9  2015 eclipse-aether-spi.jar -> ../../java/eclipse-aether-spi.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Dec  9  2015 eclipse-aether-transport-wagon.jar -> ../../java/eclipse-aether-transport-wagon.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Dec  9  2015 eclipse-aether-util.jar -> ../../java/eclipse-aether-util.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Dec  9  2015 guava.jar -> ../../java/guava.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Dec  9  2015 guice.jar -> ../../java/guice.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Dec  9  2015 javax.inject.jar -> ../../java/atinject-jsr330-tck-1.0.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Dec  9  2015 jsoup.jar -> ../../java/jsoup.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Dec  9  2015 maven-aether-provider-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-aether-provider.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Dec  9  2015 maven-artifact-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-artifact.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Dec  9  2015 maven-builder-support-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-builder-support.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Dec  9  2015 maven-compat-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-compat.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dec  9  2015 maven-core-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-core.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Dec  9  2015 maven-embedder-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-embedder.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Dec  9  2015 maven-model-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-model.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Dec  9  2015 maven-model-builder-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-model-builder.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Dec  9  2015 maven-plugin-api-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-plugin-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Dec  9  2015 maven-repository-metadata-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-repository-metadata.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Dec  9  2015 maven-settings-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-settings.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Dec  9  2015 maven-settings-builder-3.x.jar -> ../../java/maven3-settings-builder.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Dec  9  2015 plexus-cipher.jar -> ../../java/plexus-cipher.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Dec  9  2015 plexus-component-annotations.jar -> ../../java/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Dec  9  2015 plexus-interpolation.jar -> ../../java/plexus-interpolation.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Dec  9  2015 plexus-sec-dispatcher.jar -> ../../java/plexus-sec-dispatcher.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Dec  9  2015 plexus-utils.jar -> ../../java/plexus-utils2.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dec  9  2015 sisu-inject.jar -> ../../java/sisu-inject.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dec  9  2015 sisu-plexus.jar -> ../../java/sisu-plexus.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Dec  9  2015 slf4j-api.jar -> ../../java/slf4j-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Dec  9  2015 slf4j-simple.jar -> ../../java/slf4j-simple.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Dec  9  2015 wagon-file.jar -> ../../java/wagon-file-2.x.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Dec  9  2015 wagon-http-shaded.jar -> ../../java/wagon-http-shaded-2.x.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Dec  9  2015 wagon-http-shared.jar -> ../../java/wagon-http-shared-2.x.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Dec  9  2015 wagon-provider-api.jar -> ../../java/wagon-provider-api-2.x.jar

/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/man:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1229 Nov 19  2015 mvn.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1240 Nov 19  2015 mvnDebug.1.gz
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `ls -lR /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9`?

Comment: Sure @Tunaki. I've added it to my original post

Comment: This is not a standard installation. The libs and Plexus Classworld are symbolic links to some other versions. And `plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar` is not normal, Maven 3.3.9 depends on `plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar`.

Comment: Whoops you're right! I just downloaded the new one once again, and it works now. Thanks a lot @Tunaki

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7, JDK 8 ->
In my case there was a problem with the .zip file, which I have taken from Maven site. I've found that there was nothing in this \boot folder. There should be that
**plexus-classworld** which shows that org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.

*for %%i in ("%MAVEN_HOME%"\boot\plexus-classworlds-*) do set CLASSWORLDS_JAR="%%i"
set CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher*

I downloaded new Maven (.tar), set MAVEN_HOME and PATH. 
Now it works.
**So CHECK THAT FOLDER. IF EMPTY, DOWNLOAD NEW ONE.**